# Azure Document Translator is not working ,But getting response code is 202

Tags: c#, azure, azure-cloud-services, language-translation

I am trying to use the Azure Document Translation Service to translate a Document from English to Janapese. The hierarchy of the BLOB is given below.

```
|-storage account
|--container (test)
|---translation-input url (ex:https://storageaccount/test/sampleTranslation.docx)
|---translation-output url (ex:https://storageaccount/test/Converted_sampleTranslation.docx)
```

I am doing with httpclient using json input:

```
{
   "inputs":[
      {
         "storageType":"File",
         "source":{
            "sourceUrl":"https://storageaccount/test/sampleTranslation.docx?sp=racwl&st=24Z&se=2025-07-31T17:58:24Z&spr=https&sv=2020-08-04&sr=c&sig=xsd%3D%3D"
         },
         "targets":[
            {
               "targetUrl":"https://storageaccount/test/Converted_sampleTranslation.docx?sp=racwl&st=kjkZ&se=2025-07-31T17:58:24Z&spr=https&sv=2020-08-04&sr=c&sig=3LT7WCD5Tn7KK1JBTxaSOs%3D",
               "language":"ja"
            }
         ]
      }
   ]
}
```

Code snippet:

```
HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
HttpRequestMessage request = new HttpRequestMessage();
{

    StringContent content = new StringContent(json, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");

    request.Method = HttpMethod.Post;
    request.RequestUri = new Uri(endpoint + route);
    request.Headers.Add("Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key", subscriptionKey);
    request.Content = content;

    HttpResponseMessage response = await client.SendAsync(request);
    string result = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
    if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
    {

        outcome = "https://storageaccount.blob.core.windows.net/test/" + fname;
      
    }
    else
        log.Error("Error in Translate Document");

}
```

I am getting response status is 202 (means successful) but there is no translation happening with specified targeturl,

Note: Same code worked as expected in few months before. But today not getting expected result. what is the issue?

Comment: 202 is Accepted. It means that it successfully handled your request but it can't give you a result yet. The response should contain an endpoint you can poll for the result, or it would have accepted a callback endpoint in the request where it can send the result when it's ready. What does the response contain?

Comment: Side note: You're using `await` on `SendAsync`. Use it on `ReadAsStringAsync` too. Don't use `.Result`, especially when this is clearly an `async` method and the *right* thing to do is easy.

Comment: Hi Madreflection,      StatusCode: 202, ReasonPhrase: 'Accepted', Version: 1.1, Content: System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionResponseContent, Headers:
{
  X-RequestId: XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
  Operation-Location: https://xxxxx.cognitiveservices.azure.com/translator/text/batch/v1.1/batches/ecc23165-ddee-4f48-8a8c-8a2c1159902d
  Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains; preload
  apim-request-id: 0d5df564-53ff-4ed2-889d-5f16c8c76145
  X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
  x-ms-region: Central US
  Date: Wed, 06 Mar 2024 16:35:48 GMT
  Content-Length: 0
}}

Comment: [Edit] the question and add that information. Comments are the wrong place for it.

Comment: If similar requests were giving you a different result before, have you checked the Azure service documentation to see if something changed at the service side? If you are not providing any version requirements in your request, it is very possible that you are now interfacing with a newer version of this API and that it changed how this particular request is handled. Services will usually default to "latest" if you don't specify a particular version in the request.

Comment: It's highly likely that the only thing that's changed is the volume of traffic being handled and the service decided to switch to asynchronous processing so its clients aren't staying connected for long periods to wait for the results.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me.

- I created two containers
- For sourcefile : `source` with `read &list`access, for translated file: `target` with `read,write&list` access, I generated container level SAS.

**`My code`:**

```cs
using Azure.AI.Translation.Document;
using Azure;
using System;

namespace ConsoleApp3
{
    public class Program
    {
        public static async Task Main()
        {
            string endpoint = "https://doctranslation2703.cognitiveservices.azure.com/";
            string apiKey = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx";
            var client = new DocumentTranslationClient(new Uri(endpoint), new AzureKeyCredential(apiKey));

            Uri target = new Uri("https://translationstrgaccount.blob.core.windows.net/target?sp=rwl&st=2024-03-28T06:20:34Z&se=2024-03-30T14:20:34Z&spr=https&sv=2022-11-02&sr=c&sig=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx");
            Uri source = new Uri("https://translationstrgaccount.blob.core.windows.net/source?sp=rl&st=2024-03-28T06:19:34Z&se=2024-03-30T14:19:34Z&spr=https&sv=2022-11-02&sr=c&sig=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx");
                
            DocumentTranslationOperation operation = await client.StartTranslationAsync(new DocumentTranslationInput(sourceUri:source,targetUri: target,"ja"));

            await operation.WaitForCompletionAsync();

            Console.WriteLine($"Succeeded: {operation.DocumentsSucceeded}");

        }
    }
}
```

### `OUTPUT`:

[image]

```
Hi! My name is Vivek

This is a English sentance.
```

[image]

it created a same name file in container with translated language.

```
過度の渇望!私の名前はヴィヴェックです

これは英語の文章です。
```

[image]